# Featured image not appearing in sidebar on blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with a page on a site i'm working on. I have the featured image set to a a section of the sidebar on all pages (ie. About Us, What we do, etc) however the image is not displaying on the page featuring the blog posts. The following is the code from the blog template page:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blog page
* 
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage SPS
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="firstSection">
    <?php query_posts('post_type=post'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <div class="meta"><?php _e('Posted'); ?>&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_date('','',''); ?></a>&nbsp;<?php _e('by'); ?>&nbsp;<?php the_author(); ?>.&nbsp;
    <?php comments_popup_link(__('Comments (0)'), __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)')); ?>
    <span class="edit-link"><?php edit_post_link(__('[Edit]')); ?></span>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="blog-text"><?php the_excerpt(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
    </div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Have I overlooked something in the code, or am I going about it the wrong way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Dalogi

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the thumbnail function anywhere in that code you posted. I usually do it with the_post_thumbnail(). Have you read the codex about doing this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail